# invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In my Qt application I wish to be able to add a tab to a non-static `QTabWidget` when the user presses a shortcut. Normally I would implement it like this:

```
File.addAction("Settings", openSettings, Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_S);
```

where `File` is a `QTabWidget` and `openSettings` is a static method. The only issue with that is that it only works for static methods, and the issue with that is that I can't access a non-static variable in a static method. As such I figured that since Qt asks for the function to be a static function I can instantiate a static `std::function<>` object as such:

```
static std::function<void(void)> openSettings_ = []() { openSettings; };
```

and call it as such

```
File.addAction("Settings", openSettings_, Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_S);
```

The issue with this is that it generates the error:

```
Error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void window::openSettings()'
```

My reasoning for this is that I am familiar with C and assumed that what Qt calls a functor is almost the same as a function pointer that pretty much is an object. As such, I assumed that if I were to instantiate a static object of type `std::function` that pointed to / executed a non-static function I would get around this issue, which is clearly not the case. How would I go about doing this, seeing as my current thought process is wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to call the function? Also, you must capture `this` in the lambda to directly call non-static member functions.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Like this? `static std::function<void(void)> openSettings_ = []() { openSettings(this); };`

Comment: That'd be: `auto openSettings_ = [this]() {this->openSettings();};`, see my answer. `[]` specifies the "capture list", the set of objects that are captured for use inside the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the immediate error is raised because you're not actually calling the function. You must *call* it: `openSettings();`.

However, this won't work. `openSettings` is non-static member function. All such normal member functions take an implicit `this` pointer to the object on which they're being invoked. This means that one cannot directly invoke the `openSettings` function without an object on which to invoke it. But `this` is not captured by the lambda you've written, meaning there's no such object.

This can be fixed by capturing `this` in the lambda, such as `auto openSettings_ = [this]() { this->openSettings(); }`;

But on the other hand, this function is acting like a slot. You should attach the signal you're interested in directly to the signal using the standard signal/slot syntax, rather than writing the separate functor. That would be something like this.

```
File.addAction("Settings", this, &(decltype(*this))::openSettings, Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_S);
```

(Note that I'm using `decltype` because I'm not sure what type `*this` is. You can substitute with the name of the class.)

Comment: The last suggestion didn't work, or maybe my interpretation of how to do it was wrong; but your first suggestion worked beautifully. Would you mind explaining what `auto` is and why the `[this]` is necessary?

Comment: `auto` instructs a C++11 or later compiler to deduce the correct type of the object. It saves on typing, is more flexible, and is less error-prone. `this` is necessary in the capture list because it's not automatically captured by default. This is a shortcoming that is addressed in later standards of C++ (might be C++17, but I can't remember). What is the error when you try the second idea?

Comment: If I changed it to `&window` which is the correct type for the function it produces the error `Error: no matching function for call to QMenu::addAction(const char [9], window*, void (window::*)(), unsigned int`

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? Is `window` a subclass of `QWidget`?

Comment: I am using version 5.12, the newest in the ubuntu repo. `window` is practically an extension of `QMainWindow`, although it defines things such as CenterWidget among other things.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that doesn't work, it seems fine on a sample app on my machine. You might try one of the other overloads, such as the [old-style signal/slot syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-2).

Comment: Is there a performance or security benefit in doing so, if not then the `auto` line seems to be fine

Comment: I would probably prefer an actual member function slot over a lambda. The performance difference will be nil, but it's less error-prone because you're guaranteed that the `this` pointer will always be valid inside the function call. But it's not a huge deal, as long as you're careful.